If Tzaddikim Generally Pitchfork-Pray, What's the Point of Singling it out in a few Specific Locations?
Sukkah 14a:

אָמַר רַבִּי (אֱלִיעֶזֶר): לָמָּה נִמְשְׁלָה תְּפִלָּתָן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים כְּעֶתֶר — לוֹמַר לָךְ: מָה עֶתֶר זֶה מְהַפֵּךְ אֶת הַתְּבוּאָה בַּגּוֹרֶן מִמָּקוֹם לְמָקוֹם, אַף תְּפִלָּתָן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים מְהַפֶּכֶת דַּעְתּוֹ שֶׁל הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מִמִּדַּת אַכְזָרִיּוּת לְמִדַּת רַחֲמָנוּת.
Rabbi Elazar said: Why are the prayers of the righteous likened to a pitchfork [eter]? It is written: “And Isaac entreated [vayetar] the Lord for his wife, because she was barren” (Genesis 25:21), to say to you: Just as this pitchfork overturns the grain on the threshing floor from place to place, so too, the prayers of the righteous overturn the mind of the Holy One, Blessed be He, from the attribute of cruelty to the attribute of mercy, and He accepts their prayers.

There are specific mentions of pitchfork-praying in several locations. Manoach in Judges 13 and Moses in Exodus 8 utilize pitchfork-prayer. But if this is true in general of Tzadikkim prayers ("so too the prayers of the righteous"/אַף תְּפִלָּתָן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים ... equals a general rule) why only use ויעתר in specific locations?
One could say that the Talmud isn't saying that Tzadikim generally pray this way .... but it sounds like they do/אַף תְּפִלָּתָן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים. We can even go deeper down the rabbit's hole:
Tzadikim don't always face אַכְזָרִיּוּת; they pray for things that may not involve changing a state of cruelty. But can we say that generally when they do pray upon experiencing אַכְזָרִיּוּת, it is a pitchfork-prayer (original question thus still stands - why only point this out on occasion)?

Where do you see as per your title, that all tzaddikim "always" pray this way?

You have GOT to take a look at Sanhedrin 103a, about Menashe the king. "Menashe the king of Yehudah in his great suffering in exile wanted to do teshuvah, and prayed to Hashem. And Hashem heard him, ויחתר לו. It should have said ויעתר לו, Hashem accepted his prayer. But this teaches us that Hashem had to make a tunnel (מחתרת) in the heavens to receive his teshuvah." https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.103a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Your translation of עתר as “pitchfork” or “shovel״, while technically correct as a noun, is improper usage. It is a verb and the meaning is about the action of transferring from one place or state of being  to another. In verb form, it also has a connotation of enriching someone or something. In the context of Yitzchok praying in that form, it was to cause his wife to have a child, which is one the 3 types of wealth mentioned in the Torah.
